# $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ stays connected after removal of an interior point

Tags: general-topology

I am self-studying Topology's connectedness and came across this simple problem:

> Show that $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ stays connected if you remove an interior point.

Visually it looks simple because $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ can be graphically represented as an $\mathbb R^2$ square with origin $(0, 0)$ as one of its vertices, therefore "punching a hole" in the middle won't make it disconnected. On the contrary, "punching a hole" in $\mathbb R^1$ interval $[1, 0]$ will make it disconnected. Unfortunately, I don't know how to say it mathematically.

Please help giving me an outline of proof, please give me also the theorem that your proof is based on. Thanks for your time and help.

PS. My class note has this version of definition: A separation of topological space $X$ is a pair $U, V$ of disjoint non-empty subsets such that $X = U \cup V.$ Space $X$ is connected if there is no separation. Thanks again.

Comment: About the PS: the sets $U$ and $V$ must both be open (or equivalently must both be closed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The square without a point is homeomorphic to a cylinder. Is the cylinder connected?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Is $[0, 1]\times[0,1]\setminus\{(x, y)\}$ *path*-connected?

Note, this method doesn't require $(x, y)$ to be an interior point of $[0, 1]\times[0, 1]$, so the result is actually true for any point of $[0, 1]\times [0, 1]$.